# Batch File to call VBS which sends keys to application

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, cmd, key

So I am trying to make a batch file that will download your search history. In doing this I need to use the keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> along with typing the name of the file. I just need to find a way to have the code automatically carry out the action of selecting all the history by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and saving it by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and then naming it `scarra history`.

I have a folder containing 4 files:

> ```
> Scarra.bat
> ChromeHistoryView.exe
> Sendkeys.bat
> Sendkeys.vbs
> ```

`Scarra.bat` is as follows:

```
call ChromeHistoryView.exe
call sendkeys.bat
pause
```

`Sendkeys.vbs` is as follows:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "^a"
```

`Sendkeys.bat` is as follows, this is what I use to try to call the bat:

```
wscript "sendkeys.vbs"
```

Comment: You're missing the Ctrl+s and Filename then you want to send an Enter key.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to Sendkeys.vbs

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "^a"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "^s"
WScript.Sleep 2000
WshShell.SendKeys "scarra history"
```

Change Sendkeys.bat to

```
cscript sendkeys.vbs
```

Comment: it still isn't calling the vbs script properly. I have tested the vbs script out and it works fine but it doesn't activate or get called when i click scarra.bat. @vince

Comment: I did some experimenting and it is not the vbs that is the problem. As a matter of fact it is the exe. It seems when i call the chromehistoryview.exe the rest of the bat file just stops. Any solution?

Comment: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_history_view.html  link has all the options to save your history.